# Random variables with undefined expectation

Tags: probability

[image: definition of undefined expectation]

These paragraphs are from p. 82 of *Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition* by Dimitri Bertsekas and John Tsitsiklis. I don't quite understand why the expectation in the last example is undefined; why is it not equal to zero?

Comment: The authors say that expectation well defined means that the series $\sum_x xp_X(x)$ converges absolutely (their definition).  The series $\sum_k 2^k p_X(2^k)=\sum_k 2^k\cdot 2^{-k}=\sum_k 1$ diverges; thus, the series $\sum_x |x|p_X(x)$ in their second example, which equals twice $\sum_k 2^k p_X(2^k)$, also diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in the last example the expectation is
$$
\sum_{k\geq2}P(X=-2^k)\times (-2^k)+
\sum_{k\geq2}P(X=2^k)\times 2^k
=
\sum_{k\geq2}\frac1{2^k}\,(-2^k)+
\sum_{k\geq2}\frac1{2^k}\, 2^k
=
-\sum_{k\geq2}1+
\sum_{k\geq2}1
$$
which is ill-defined as a difference of two infinite sums. Of course you can regroup terms and obtain an infinite sum of zeros, but infinite sums are tricky (in a similar fashion you could show that the difference of infinite sums is $1$, $-1$ of any integer value).

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_x\lvert x\rvert p_X(x)=\sum_{k\geq2}\lvert2^k\rvert2^{-k}+\sum_{k\geq2}\lvert-2^k\rvert2^{-k}=\infty.$