# What kind of entity is the expectation of a random variable?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given a probability space $(Ω, \mathcal F, P)$ and an integrable random variable $ξ: Ω \to \Bbb R$, what kind of entity is the expectation of $ξ$ i.e. $E(ξ)=\int_Ω ξdP$? My sense is that we have a functional (or an operator) $RV\mapsto\Bbb R$, where $RV\subseteq F:=\{f|f \space \mathrm {function}\}$ is the set of random variables. I found nowhere in bibliography a characterization of expectation 's nature.

Comment: If you want, you can see the expectation as a mapping from all integrable random variables to the real numbers, for example you may see it as $$\mathbb E: L^1(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)\to\mathbb R.$$

Comment: The mapping is [not necessarily defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123505/random-variables-with-undefined-expectation) @Maximilian

Comment: However the mapping $L^1 (Ω, \mathcal F, P) \mapsto \Bbb R$ is well defined -isn' t so?

Comment: @windows9 Since the random variables are in $L^1$, it is well-defined :)

Comment: Of course it is.